# Test coverage is 100% but assertion is failing

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I have written a test class for a sample apex code but the issue with this is that the code coverage which is being displayed is 100% although there is an assertion exception

```
Apex Class:
trigger AccountAddressTrigger on Account (before insert,before update){
    for (Account a: Trigger.new) {
        if (a.Match_Billing_Address__c==TRUE && a.BillingPostalCode!= null){
             a.ShippingPostalCode = a.BillingPostalCode;
           }
    }  
}

Test Class:

@istest
public class TestAccountAddressTrigger {
@istest
    public static void testAccountTrigger(){
        List<Account> listAccount = new List<Account>();
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Trigger', Match_Billing_Address__c = TRUE, BillingPostalCode = '10001');
        listAccount.add(acc);
        insert listAccount;
        System.assertEquals('10001', listAccount[0].ShippingPostalCode);
    }
}
```

Exception: System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 10001, Actual: null

P.S. Newbie in apex programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to requery the account to get the updated fields from the account trigger call. The reference to the account in your test class does not get any updates from the trigger.

```
@istest
public class TestAccountAddressTrigger {
@istest
    public static void testAccountTrigger(){
        List<Account> listAccount = new List<Account>();
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Trigger', Match_Billing_Address__c = TRUE, BillingPostalCode = '10001');

        listAccount.add(acc);
        insert listAccount;

        // Adding the following line fixes the issue
        listAccount = [SELECT ShippingPostalCode FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id];
        System.assertEquals('10001', listAccount[0].ShippingPostalCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works